# Stop a function from running

Tags: javascript

everyone:

I have the following code:

```
let button = document.querySelector("#button");

function outer() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function() {
    counter ++;
    console.log(counter)
    if (counter === 5) {
      console.log("Five")
      return; 
    };
  }
}

let increase = outer();

button.addEventListener("click", increase);
```

I'd like to ask the user if she wants to keep on playing. If the answer is yes, counter will be set to 0 and the game will start over; however, if the answer is no, the function will stop. The problem is that the function doesn't return when counter is equal to 5. Why?

Comment: What do you mean with "the function doesn't return"? It returns exactly what you programmed it to return: `undefined`. And of course people can keep on clicking as much as they like, because once you hit `counter === 5`, you don't remove the event listener from your button.

Comment: Create an `new` Object using a class, constructor, or Object literal. Use a method to set a property value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the click listener once the `counter` variable's value reaches five.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("#button");

function outer() {
  let counter = 0;
  return function() {
    counter++;
    console.log(counter)
    if (counter === 5) {
      console.log("Five")
      button.removeEventListener("click", increase); /** remove the listener **/
    };
  }
}

let increase = outer();

button.addEventListener("click", increase);
```

```html
<button id="button">click me</button>
```

> Learn more about [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) function.